# Excel HTML and Hidden tabs

Tags: html, microsoft-excel

I don't know if this is possible but I'd like to publish a Workbook that has several tabs.  The first tab has links to the other tabs but I want to hide these so they don't show when I publish the HTML.  I still want the links to work and navigate to the hidden tabs but I don't want the tabs themselves to show on the 'home Excel' html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this VBA - it will make a hidden macro "hide" that will hide the "sheet2" and can only be unhidden by changing the value of the hidden macro, or executing a different macro that sets the `visible` property to `false` or `true`

```
Private Sub Hide()

Sheets("sheet2").Visible = xlVeryHidden

End Sub
```